# C# How to simultaneously Scroll and Zoom the image using v/h Scroll-bars and TrackBar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ocr

When i load the image to the Mainform my code draws some red rectangles in the image. I have set v&h Scroll-Bars and a TrackBar to Zoom and scroll. And they work pretty fine when used separately.

This is how it should look when I zoom and scroll:

[image]

But when I use both I get these red rectangles shifted in the image.

The shifted rectangles after zooming and scrolling:

[image]

I am calling Draw (Graphics g) which is in another class from MainForm_Paint as shown:

```
private void MainForm_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)

{
        // Call the Draw function of the ImageProcessing class
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-hScrollBar.Value, -vScrollBar.Value);
        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(ImageZoomTrackbar.Value / 100f, ImageZoomTrackbar.Value / 100f);
        imageprocessing.Draw(e.Graphics);    
    }
```

The Other class:

```
private EImageBW8 sourceImage = new EImageBW8();
 private EOCR ocrTool = new EOCR();
public void Initialize()
        {
            try
            {                    
                OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
                if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

                {
                    /// Load the image featuring the characters       
                    sourceImage.Load(dlg.FileName);                         
                }                    
                /// Set the characters color
                ocrTool.TextColor = EOCRColor.WhiteOnBlack;

                // Build blobs
                ocrTool.BuildObjects(sourceImage);

                // Build chars
                ocrTool.FindAllChars(sourceImage);
            }
            catch (EException exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }    
        }
    public void Draw(Graphics g)
            {
                try
                {
                    /// Exit if no image has been loaded
                    if (sourceImage.IsVoid) return;

                    /// Draw the source image
                    sourceImage.Draw(g, g.Transform.Elements[0], g.Transform.Elements[3], g.Transform.OffsetX, g.Transform.OffsetY);

                    /// Draw the character Patterns
                    ocrTool.DrawChars(g, g.Transform.Elements[0], g.Transform.Elements[3], g.Transform.OffsetX, g.Transform.OffsetY);

                }
                catch (EException exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }        
            }
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: You need to redraw those rectangles again and again while scrolling and zooming according to position and zoom level.

Comment: It's worth showing `sourceImage.Draw` and `ocrToll.Draw` methods, but from the code it looks like you are passing some transformation arguments. They should really receive `Graphics` only and draw against (0,0) point unscaled, the graphics transform will do the necessary transformations. Also you should exchange the order of the `TranslateTransform` and `ScaleTransform` lines, because by default they are prepended, i.e. your current code first scales, then translates which IMO is incorrect.

Comment: I have tried to all what suggested, but i can not find a working way to redraw the rectangles each time scrolling position and track-bar position changes. Do you have any suggestion how i can do this.

Comment: Handle the corresponding events ([ScrollableControl.Scroll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.scroll(v=vs.110).aspx) and [TrackBar.ValueChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.valuechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)) and call [Invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have tried this as well  but still the same.

Comment: I think you didn't get correctly my first comment. You should not use `g.Transform` properties in your drawing code.

Comment: I got it, but still same problem, i think it is something related to e-vision libraries which i am not familiar with, thus ill remove track-bar.